# Ansible, Is there a way to run the curl command on the Control Node rather than the Managed Node?

Tags: ansible

Modules such as `shell`, `uri`, and `command` use the `curl` command in the managed node.

I want to run `curl` commands on the Control Node, not the Managed Node.

Is it possible in Ansible?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you may have a look into [Controlling where tasks run: delegation and local actions](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html) and

- use `delegate_to` for [Delegating tasks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#delegating-tasks)
- or `hosts: localhost` for running the [Playbook local](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#delegating-tasks) at all.

**Further Q&A**

- [Difference between `hosts: localhost` and `connection: local`](https://superuser.com/questions/1560645/)

Comment: Thank you.
I solved it by using 'connection:local' instead of 'delegate_to' with the command module. Are the two different?